# GTX770 Vs GTX960 for lightroom and photoshop

Tags: graphics-cards

I want advice from you, which would be better between GTX770 2GB & GTX960 2GB.

I know GTX770 performs better in benchmarks, because it has 256 bits, and the GTX960 has 128 bits, but the gtx 960 is newer and support DX12 and I think it has better support for 4k videos. I'm a not gamer.

But which better for photoshop & lightroom ?

My config:

CPU i7 3770K

16GB RAM

Asus P8Z77 PRO

Samsung SSD 256GB for system.

monitor LG 27UL550-W (4K Support with HDR10)

I'm on windows 7 64bit but I can switch To win10.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

The GTX 770 will be faster for video encoding and *most* GPU-accelerated applications.

It loses to the 960 in a lot of ways other than performance though.

1. It requires much more power than the GTX 960. (600W vs 450W)
2. No HDR support, and no HDMI 2.0
3. Models with 4GB VRAM are hard to come by.
4. Older video codec support & slower on-board encoding chip.

I would not recommend buying a *6 year old* GPU unless it was super *cheap*.
Even the 960 is starting to become hard to recommend itself if you compare it to the currently available GPUs near its performance such as the GTX 1050 Ti or GTX 1650

Comment: Here's a GTX 970 card for $100. I'm not sure what is better for GPU-accelerated apps, either the GTX 970 or the GTX 960. https://www.pcswaps.com/product/5e090c01e7b1fd21cf7943a2